# Eliminar registro usando un modal de confirmacion en laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla de registros que cuando le doy click en el botón de eliminar en uno de dichos registros, se abre un modal de bootstrap 4 para confirmar la acción. 
El problema es que siempre elimina el ultimo registro creado, si quiero eliminar el primero o el segundo, de igual forma elimina el ultimo... 
Solo he visto que pasa cuando tengo el modal agregado y **si** funciona bien sin el modal. Estuve viendo que siempre toma el id del ultimo registro pero no se por qué pasa...

Este es el código de la vista:

```
<table class="table text-center">
        <thead>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Municipio</th>
            <th>Opciones</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($carteras as $cartera)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$cartera->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$cartera->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$cartera->depto}}</td>
                <td>{{$cartera->municipio}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="" class="badge-md badge-pill badge-success">Ver</a>
                    <a href="{{route('carteras.edit', $cartera->id)}}" class="badge-md badge-pill badge-primary">Editar</a>
                    <a href="" class="badge-md badge-pill badge-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <!------ ESTE ES EL MODAL QUE SE MUESTRA AL DAR CLICK EN EL BOTON "ELIMINAR" ------>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header d-flex justify-content-center">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p class="text-center">Está seguro(a) de eliminar la cartera {{$cartera->name}} / {{$cartera->id}}?</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE', 'action'=>['CarterasController@destroy', $cartera->id]]) !!}
                            {!! Form:: submit('Eliminar', ['class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-default'])!!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--fin modal-->
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

el controlador:

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $cartera = Cartera::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return redirect()->route('carteras.index');
}
```

Asi es la vista de los registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: coloca tu codigo javascript! para poder ayudarte mejor!

Comment: Estoy utilizando bootstrap 4 y el hace el trabajo de abrir el modal... no utilicé un codigo adicional de Js para su funcionamiento

Comment: bueno tu error es simple todos los eliminar llaman al mismo modal `data-target="#exampleModalCenter"` la solucion: cambiar el target a `data-target="#exampleModalCenter{{$cartera->id}}"` y el modal a `<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter{{$cartera->id}}"` asi cada modal hara referencia a si mismo!

Comment: Ok. gracias. Funciona perfecto...